# Can Informatica mapping variable have value from Informatica builtin variable? like SESSSTARTTIME

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am trying to get the SESSSTARTTIME in a mapping variable. Is it possible? I don't want to use an expression for single output port.

Comment: SESSSTARTTIME itself is a inbuilt variable. Why do you want to assign to a mapping variable again?

Comment: Not sure if that's possible, but have you tried setting it as default?